# How to speed up Mathematica replacement of matrix elements

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have several 100x15 matrices; one of them is a distance. When elements of that matrix exceed a bound, I want to reset those elements to zero and also reset the corresponding elements of three other matrices to zero. Here's my silly way (but it works):

```
Do[ If[ xnow[[i, j]] > L, xnow[[i, j]] = 0.;
                  cellactvA[[i, j ]]  = 0.;
                  cellactvB[[i, j ]]  = 0.;
                  cellactvC[[i, j ]]  = 0.;   ], (* endIF  *)
   { i, 1, nstrips}, {j, 1, ncells}       ];  (* endDO *)
```

I tried `ReplacePart`:

```
 xnow = ReplacePart[ xnow, Position[ xnow, x_?(# > L &) ] ]
```

(something like this, I don't have it handy; it was done correctly enough to execute), but it was as slow as the loop and did not produce the correct replacement structure in matrix xnow. Please advise on how to do this in a way that is reasonably quick, as this calc is inside another loop (over time) that executes many many times. The overall calculation is of course, now, very slow. Thanks in advance.

---

Here is how I did this in R; very simple and quick:

```
    # -- find indices of cells outside window
indxoutRW  <- which( xnow > L, arr.ind=T )

    # -- reset cells outside window
cellrateA[indxoutRW] <- 0 
cellrateB[indxoutRW] <- 0 
cellrateC[indxoutRW] <- 0 

    # -- move reset cells back to left side
 xnow[indxoutRW]    <- xnow[indxoutRW] - L
```

Comment: Hello Bill. Your question is fine here. We also have a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica?referrer=_mAZyyA742Y1) for creating a mathematica specific site. Please consider committing to that to take it off the ground.

Comment: Not a complete answer but an observation. The slowness is due to the > check and I could not find any inbuilt function that performs that check faster than the pattern check _?(#>L&).

I think most of the speedup of the suggested solutions can be attributed to improvements over using a Do loop from SpareseArray, MapThread.

The inbuilt functions for < is Chop[xnow,L] which is about ten times faster. Ruebenko figured out that you can use mask = UnitStep[L - xnow] to create a mask and then just do xnow * mask. UnitStep is about fifty times faster than the Do loop (on a 1000x1000 matrix).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this:

```
Timing[
 matrixMask2 = UnitStep[limit - $xnow];
 xnow = $xnow*matrixMask2;
 cellactvA2 = $a*matrixMask2;
 cellactvB2 = $b*matrixMask2;
 cellactvC2 = $c*matrixMask2;
 ]
```

If you want to write fast code one thing to make sure is to check that On["Packing"] does not gives messages; or at least that you understand them and know that they are not an issue.

**Edit for OP comment:**

```
mask = UnitStep[limit - xnow];
{xnow*mask, cellactvA2*mask, cellactvB2*mask, cellactvC2*mask}
```

Hope this helps, you still need to set limit.

Comment: To get the xnow matric as well do `xnow = $xnow*matrixMask2`

Comment: I think you are the winner. This is about 50 times faster than the `Do` loop on a 1000x1000 matrix.

Comment: No, you should tests other stuff too - does it compile, or does the compiled form of the Do loop do well. How, does using N[UnitStep[..]] influence performance. This is just an idea of a direction.

Comment: I assume mma will use a compliled version of `UnitStep` here since the arguments are numeric.

Comment: Excellent! This is more than 30x faster than the other suggested methods on on 2K and 3K matrices. Wrapping with `N[..]` or `SparseArray[.]` does not help- actually it almost doubles the time.

Comment: @kguler, thanks for checking. Did you also try the compiled versions?

Comment: I checked, compilation does not improve things.

Comment: Pretty impressive - I thought my method would be faster because in your method also unaffected elements must be multiplied, but your code seems to be still 1.5x - 2x faster. +1

Comment: Thanks, Lenoid, you just made my 1000 ;-)

Comment: @ruebenko Congrats! I am very happy to be the one to do it :). But, seriously, your code is the best for this problem, of the solutions posted so far, and I hope that the final vote count will reflect that.

Comment: Late last night I thought of `matrixMask2 = Sign[Clip[limit - $xnow, {0, Infinity}]]`, but `UnitStep` (which I forgot about) is a third faster than that.

Comment: I'm going to get yelled at for this, but...  This solution is, I'm sure, a very elegant answer but as I indicated in the original question, I'm a novice at MMA. (That part was edited out.) I have no idea what $xnow $a $b $c are or what $ does. The responses here seem to be aimed within the community of experts, forgetting the person who asked the question in the first place. I tried this code as presented above and it ran forever and I had to abort it. I recognize that this website is aimed more at higher-level folks, so perhaps I'm in the wrong place. Thanks to all for the efforts, anyway.

Comment: @bill, I'll edit my post later to reflect your comments. $ means nothing special, I just used so that I could use the example data from below. But now for dinner.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I did:                       matrixMask = UnitStep[L - xnow];
           xnow        = xnow*matrixMask;
           cellactvA   = cellactvA*matrixMask;
           cellactvB   = cellactvB*matrixMask;
           cellactvC   = cellactvC*matrixMask; and it does work. The calcs are a bit faster now, but it turns out there's a FunctionInterpolation that's taking a lot of time also. I'll work on that and maybe write that up, later. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 8):

The following will be based on SparseArrays, avoid extraneous stuff and very fast:

```
extractPositionFromSparseArray[
   HoldPattern[SparseArray[u___]]] := {u}[[4, 2, 2]];
positionExtr[x_List, n_] := 
   extractPositionFromSparseArray[
     SparseArray[Unitize[x - n], Automatic, 1]]

replaceWithZero[mat_, flatZeroPositions_List, type : (Integer | Real) : Real] :=
  Module[{copy = Flatten@mat},
     copy[[flatZeroPositions]] = If[type === Integer, 0, 0.];
     Partition[copy, Last[Dimensions[mat]]]];

getFlatZeroDistancePositions[distanceMat_, lim_] :=
  With[{flat = Flatten[distanceMat]},
     With[{originalZPos = Flatten@ positionExtr[flat , 0]},
       If[originalZPos  === {}, #, Complement[#, originalZPos ]] &@
         Flatten@positionExtr[Clip[flat , {0, lim}, {0, 0}], 0]]];
```

Now, we generate our matrices, making sure that they are packed:

```
{xnow, cellactvA, cellactvB, cellactvC} = 
   Developer`ToPackedArray /@ RandomReal[10, {4, 100, 15}];
```

Here is the benchmark for doing this 1000 times:

```
In[78]:= 
Do[
  With[{L = 5},
    With[{flatzpos = getFlatZeroDistancePositions[xnow,L]},
       Map[replaceWithZero[#,flatzpos ]&,{xnow,cellactvA,cellactvB,cellactvC}]]
  ],
  {1000}]//Timing

Out[78]= {0.203,Null}
```

Note that there was no unpacking in the process, but you have to ensure that you have your matrices packed from the start, and that you pick the correct type (Integer or Real) for the `replaceWithZero` function.

Comment: Very nice Leonid! The only thing bothering me is that to write such a solution in Mathematica takes too much time (maybe not for you, but you are a master of course). I think Mathematica should be as fast as R or Matlab out of the box, for loops. I.e. there should be more smart optimizations behind the scenes. Talk to TWJ or RG maybe ...

Comment: @Rolf Thanks! I have the same feeling regarding loops. This is a hard task for Mathematica due to its symbolic nature though. I am sure it will get there eventually though. Note that Oliver's solution is still both faster and simpler than mine (something I did not expct for this problem, since I thought additional multiplications of unaffected elements in his solution would be more  costly).

Comment: Leonid, I see you use `extractPositionFromSparseArray` rather than `["AdjacencyLists"]`.  Habit or deliberate?

Answer (score 3):

Yet another method which seems to be fast

```
xnow = $xnow; a = $a; b = $b; c = $c;
umask = Unitize@Map[If[# > limit, 0, #] &, xnow, {2}];
xnow = xnow*umask; a = a*umask; b = b*umask; c = c*umask;
```

Based on limited testing in Nasser's setup it seems it is as fast as the `SparseArray`-based mask.

Edit: Can combine with `SparseArray` to get a slight speed-up

```
umask2=SparseArray[Unitize@Map[If[# > limit, 0, #] &, xnow, {2}]];
xnow = xnow*umask2; a = a*umask2; b = b*umask2; c = c*umask2;
```

Edit 2: Inspired by ruebenko's solution, another built-in function (not nearly as fast as `UnitStep` but much faster than others):

```
umask3 = Clip[xnow, {limit, limit}, {1, 0}];
xnow = xnow*umask3; a = a*umask3; b = b*umask3; c = c*umask3;
```

Answer (score 2):

may be

```
(*data*)
nRow = 5; nCol = 5;
With[{$nRow = nRow, $nCol = nCol},
  xnow = Table[RandomReal[{1, 3}], {$nRow}, {$nCol}];
  cellactvA = cellactvB = cellactvC = Table[Random[], {$nRow}, {$nCol}]
  ];
limit = 2.0;
```

now do the replacement

```
pos = Position[xnow, x_ /; x > limit]; 

{cellactvA, cellactvB, cellactvC} = 
  Map[ReplacePart[#, pos -> 0.] &, {cellactvA, cellactvB, cellactvC}];
```

**edit(1)**

Here is a quick speed comparing the 4 methods above, the LOOP, and then Brett, me, and Verbeia. May be someone can double check them.  I used the same data for all. created random data once, then used it for each test. Same limit (called L) I used matrix size of 2,000 by 2,000.

So speed Timing numbers below does not include data allocation.

I run the tests once.

This is what I see:

### For 2,000 by 2,000 matrices:

1. Bill (loop): 16 seconds
2. me (`ReplacPart`): 21 seconds
3. Brett (`SparseArray`): 7.27 seconds
4. Verbeia (`MapThread`): 32 seconds

### For 3,000 by 3,000 matrices:

1. Bill (loop): 37 seconds
2. me (`ReplacPart`): 48 seconds
3. Brett (`SparseArray`): 16 seconds
4. Verbeia (`MapThread`): 79 seconds

So, it seems to be that `SparseArray` is the fastest. (but please check to make sure I did not break something)

code below:

**data generation**

```
(*data*)
nRow = 2000;
nCol = 2000;

With[{$nRow = nRow, $nCol = nCol},
  $xnow = Table[RandomReal[{1, 3}], {$nRow}, {$nCol}];
  $a = $b = $c = Table[Random[], {$nRow}, {$nCol}]
  ];

limit = 2.0;
```

**ReplacePart test**

```
xnow = $xnow;
a = $a;
b = $b;
c = $c;

Timing[
  pos = Position[xnow, x_ /; x > limit];
  {xnow, a, b, c} = Map[ReplacePart[#, pos -> 0.] &, {xnow, a, b, c}]][[1]]
```

**SparseArray test**

```
xnow = $xnow;
a = $a;
b = $b;
c = $c;
Timing[
  matrixMask = 
   SparseArray[Thread[Position[xnow, _?(# > limit &)] -> 0.], 
    Dimensions[xnow], 1.]; xnow = xnow*matrixMask;
  a = a*matrixMask;
  b = b*matrixMask;
  c = c*matrixMask
  ][[1]]
```

**MapThread test**

```
xnow = $xnow;
a = $a;
b = $b;
c = $c;
Timing[
  {xnow, a, b, c} = 
   MapThread[Function[{x, y}, If[x > limit, 0, y]], {xnow, #}, 
      2] & /@ {xnow, a, b, c}
  ][[1]]
```

**loop test**

```
xnow = $xnow;
a = $a;
b = $b;
c = $c;
Timing[
  Do[If[xnow[[i, j]] > limit,
    xnow[[i, j]] = 0.;
    a[[i, j]] = 0.;
    b[[i, j]] = 0.;
    c[[i, j]] = 0.
    ],
   {i, 1, nRow}, {j, 1, nCol}
   ]
  ][[1]]
```

**edit(2)**

There is something really bothering me with all of this. I do not understand how a loop can be faster that the specialized commands for this purpose?

I wrote a simple loop test in Matlab, like Bill had using R, and I getting much lower timings there also.  I hope an expert can come up with a much faster method, because now I am not too happy with this.

For 3,000 by 3,000 matrix, I am getting

```
Elapsed time is 0.607026 seconds.
```

This is more than 20 times faster than the SparseArray method, and it is just a loop!

```
%test, on same machine, 4GB ram, timing uses cpu timing using tic/toc
%allocate data
nRow = 3000;
nCol = 3000;

%generate a random matrix of real values
%between 1 and 3
xnow = 1 + (3-1).*rand(nRow,nRow);

%allocate the other 3 matrices
a=zeros(nRow,nCol);
b=a;
c=b;

%set limit
limit=2;

%engine
tstart=tic;

for i=1:nRow
    for j=1:nCol
        if xnow(i,j) > limit
            xnow(i,j) = 0;
            a(i,j) = 0;
            b(i,j) = 0;
            c(i,j) = 0;
        end
    end
end
toc(tstart)
```

fyi: using cputime() gives similar values.as tic/toc.

Comment: I am still struggling just to find the correct commands to use. Once I master this part, I will then go on to the next phase, which is to filter out those that are slow :)

Answer (score 2):

`ReplacePart` is notoriously slow.

`MapThread` should do what you want - note the third argument.

```
{xnow, cellactvA, cellactvB, cellactvC} = 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 10, 5}]
L = 0.6;
MapThread[If[#1 > L, 0, #2] &, {xnow, xnow}, 2]
```

And for all four matrices

```
{xnow, cellactvA, cellactvB, cellactvC} =
 MapThread[Function[{x, y}, If[x > L, 0, y]], {xnow, #}, 
  2] & /@ {xnow, cellactvA, cellactvB, cellactvC}
```

Comment: Hi- I tried this and it doesn't work. I used the variable L where you have 0.6 above. It spits out some errors and grinds for a long time. (Tag Times Protected)....???

Comment: Yes, it is defined earlier in the notebook. Do I need both MapThread statements or just the last one? I tried it both ways; I'll try it again.

Comment: Just the last one. I showed both so that you could see what was going on - functional programming is quite unfamiliar if you have programmed in other languages.

Comment: Oh, I've just realised the issue -- the cell defining xnow etc should be in a separate cell to the `MapThread` command. I assumed you would realise this. If necessary, put a `;` after the bit that says `RandomReal[...]`. Put each statement into a separate cell and you'll be fine.

Comment: Ok, I tried it exactly as you have it here, not in my main calcs; it does run and shows zeroes presumably where they should be (>0.6 values replaced) but the matrices themselves are not changed. "xnow" before and after executing the MapThread is unchanged. I need it to have the zeroes in it after the MapThread. ????

Comment: See the edited version. Yes, you need to reassign `xnow` etc, to this `MapThread` expression. These are the sorts of basics that would be revealed in an introductory tutorial. Sorry, I had assumed you would be familiar with the idea of assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Does this approach work for you?

```
matrixMask = 
 SparseArray[Thread[Position[xnow, _?(# > 0.75 &)] -> 0.], 
  Dimensions[xnow], 1.]; 
xnow = xnow * matrixMask;
cellactvA = cellactvA * matrixMask;
cellactvB = cellactvB * matrixMask;
cellactvC = cellactvC * matrixMask;
```

The basic idea is to create a matrix that is zero where your threshold is crossed, and one everywhere else.  Then we use element-wise multiplication to zero out the appropriate elements in the various matrices.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that works, but is at least as slow as the original loop. (This is being executed about 2000 times....)

Comment: @bill, please see my edit(1). I see that the SparseArray method is at least twice as fast as the loop method. I only tried it for 2,000 by 2,000 matrices. You can try for larger sizes, code is below.